# Extract data from gaussian log file by python

Tags: extract, gaussian, logfile

I have a log file (n_10_osf.log) I want to extract HOMO -LUMO , total energy and other parameters from this log file by python?

i want to print all these values which i needed  by a python code by inserting a gaussian log file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.